# White-Label a UWP Application

Tags: win-universal-app, white-labelling

I am about to start development on an UWP Application. One of the last minute requirements was to be able to support white-labeling the application for our partners.  Does anyone have any experience doing this using the Universal Windows Platform that would be willing to give me some insight on resources I should be looking at?

Some basic questions I have is:

1. Is it possible?  I read about it being done with iOS and Android.
2. How do you create the AppPackage for each partner?
3. Localization differences?  Where one localization may refer to it as one product, but another refers to it as the other product.

Or is this something where I would bundle everything up and send it to the partner to create their own upload?  If this is the case, is there a how-to on that?

Some of these might be basic questions, but this is the first time I have created a white-label application, so it is all new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just replied to another one topic and looks that screenshot is still needed)

When you submit App to store you can find option:

[image]

This way you can make your app visible only to your partners. And you can also register as many apps as you like (each one for separate partner)

Or you can distribute your app thrue [Windows Store for Business](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/business-store/).
Take a look also at this link, it might be helpful for you
[Distribute LOB apps to enterprises](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/distribute-lob-apps-to-enterprises)

Comment: We are wanting to distribute the app under our own name to the general public, however; we want to be able to let our partners redistribute the app using a name they choose as well.  So, if we named it "AppX" our partner may want to distribute it as "My AppX".  This also means that screen shots and splash screens, localization, etc may change as well based on the partner.

Comment: That I have understand. So, if you want to distribute your app from Windows Store you can show App only to your partners. You can create different packages for different partners. But only you will be able to change screenshots, splash screens and localization etc...